# Can Google Maps code run in Excel's Webbrowser control?

Tags: javascript, html, excel, google-maps

I wrote a little script with Google Maps API, and it run perfectly fine with either Chrome or IE. However, when I tried to use Excel's Webbrowser control to run the map, it shows an error message and the page doesn't load properly.

I am not sure what's going on there. I suspect there is something wrong with my JavaScript/HTML code since I have no experience with these two languages at all before. The error message excel provided is:

> An error has occurred in the script on this page. 
>   Line:0, 
>   Char:0, 
>   Error: Script error, 
>   Code: 0, 
>   URL: https://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/21/7/intl/en_au/main.js"

My idea is there is something wrong with the HTML part, but I am not sure.

My code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Circle & Info</title>
    <style>
        html, body, #map-canvas {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;signed_in=true"></script>
    <script>
        var locations = [
        ['St. Martin Catholic School', ' 4228', 42.9698, -81.2537, ' 266', ' 386', 'FE7569', '-1', ''],
        ['St. John Catholic French Immersion School', ' 4045', 42.97827, -81.2335, ' 350', ' 334', 'FE7569', '-1', ''],
        ['St. Mary Choir Catholic School', ' 4244', 42.988, -81.2284, ' 231', ' 311', 'FE7569', '-1', ''],
        ['Holy Rosary Catholic School', ' 3312', 42.9663, -81.2302, ' 165', ' 234', 'FE7569', '-1', ''],
        ['St. Michael Catholic School, London', ' 4301', 43.0042, -81.2446, ' 182', ' 268', 'FE7569', '-1', ''],
        ['New School', ' 99999',42.9809401, -81.2548567, ' ', ' 100', '9', '0', 'Not']
        ];
 var markers = [];
 var map;
 var circles = [];
 var radius;
 function initialize() {
     radius = document.getElementById("radius_value").value;
     if (radius == "" || isNaN(radius)) {
         radius = 2;
     }
     radius = Number(radius * 1000);
     var myOptions = {
         center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.9809401, -81.2548567),
         zoom: 8,
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     };
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("default"), myOptions);
     setMarkers(radius);
 }
 var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
 function setMarkers(radius) {
     var i;
     for (i = 0; i != markers.length; ++i) {
         markers[i].setMap(null);
     }
     for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            var name = locations[i][0];
            var sfis = locations[i][1];
            var lat = locations[i][2];
            var long = locations[i][3];
            var ade = locations[i][4];
            var otg = locations[i][5];
            var pinColor = locations[i][6];
            var Indicator = locations[i][7];
            var Duplicate = locations[i][8];
            var latlngset = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
            var pinImage;
            if (Indicator==0){
            pinImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_xpin_letter&chld=pin|N|"+pinColor,
                new google.maps.Size(21, 34),
                new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                new google.maps.Point(10, 34));
            } else if (Indicator==-1) {
                if (Duplicate=="Duplicate") {
            pinImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_xpin_letter&chld=pin_sleft|"+(i+1)+"|"+pinColor,
                new google.maps.Size(50, 34),
                new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                new google.maps.Point(20, 34));
                } else {
            pinImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_xpin_letter&chld=pin|"+(i+1)+"|"+pinColor,
                new google.maps.Size(50, 34),
                new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                new google.maps.Point(10, 34));
                }
            } else {
                if (Duplicate =="Duplicate") {
            pinImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_xpin_letter&chld=pin_sright|"+Indicator+"|"+pinColor,
                new google.maps.Size(50, 50),
                new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                new google.maps.Point(0, 34));
                } else {
            pinImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_xpin_letter&chld=pin|"+Indicator+"|"+pinColor,
                new google.maps.Size(50, 50),
                new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                new google.maps.Point(10, 34));}
            }
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                title: name,
                draggable:true,
                position: latlngset,
                icon: pinImage,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
            });
            markers.push(marker);
            map.setCenter (marker.getPosition())
            var populationOptions = {
                strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                strokeOpacity: 0.2,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                fillColor: '#FF0000',
                fillOpacity: 0.1,
                map: map,
                center: latlngset,
                radius: radius
            };
            var content = '<div id="content">' +
                '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">' + name +'</h1>' +
                '<div id="bodyContent">' +
                '<p><b>SFIS ID:</b>' + sfis + '</p>' +
                '<p><b>ADE:</b>' + ade + '</p>' +
                '<p><b>OTG:</b>' + otg + '</p>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>';
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, content, infowindow) {
                return function() {
                    infowindow.setContent(content);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                };
            })(marker, content, infowindow));
            new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions);
            bounds.extend(markers[i].position);
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
    <div style="position:fixed;top:10px;right:200px;z-index:2000">
        <input type="text" id="radius_value">
        <button onclick="initialize()">Change Radius (km)</button>
    </div>
    <div id="default" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your html and script are fine, my guess is it's the ms excel thats got the problem

Comment: what code did you put in the activex control in your excel? It's advisable to open a blank page first before writing your html code... in excel that is

Comment: In excel, i just wrote: Me.WebBrowser1.Navigate ("C:\Users\ZengYi\Documents\schoolmap.html")

Comment: First of all it should be .HTML not .gif  , second of all you should open a blank HTML file first before opening your HTML file in excel

Comment: That file gives a 404, both HTML and gif

Comment: That file direct to the html page I created in my local drive.

Comment: By the way, what do you mean by opening a blank HTML file first?

Comment: It just works trust me. Btw you don't need the me. What version of excel are you using?

Comment: I think your code in excel is wrong and I think you need a live page. Have you used the web control before? What vsn are you using?

Comment: MS 2010. I guess you are right, Me. is not necessary here.

Comment: This is my first time using such control. I tried to load other pages and it just works fine, such as "WebBrowser1.Navigate ("www.google.ca")"

Comment: Try with http://www.rachelgallen.com/googlemap.html

Comment: No luck, excel returns 2 error, and only the map is loaded, not the markers and circles. It dose exactly the same as loading from my local drive. Does it mean there's something wrong with my excel? Does it works fine on your machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your html code looks fine and that your excel code may be the problem
I have uploaded your file onto my server
Try the following code in your webcontrol

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate ("about:blank")
WebBrowser1.Navigate ("www.rachelgallen.com/googlemap.html")
```

OR

Put a cmd button on your page. Type the url into a cell above your webcontrol. In the code of the cmd button, declare a variable e.g. linkname and set it equal to the Range(cell). Then, type (e.g., where Sheet1 is the name of your sheet and C1 is where you typed the URL)

```
linkname=Sheets("Sheet1").Range(C1)
Call Sheets("Sheet1").WebControl1.Navigate (linkname)
```

and see if that works

Comment: It still shows the error message and unable to load the page fully. May be there is something wrong with my excel? I don't know. I will find a way to walk around the problem. Thanks for your help, appreciate it.

Comment: I have another solution. Put a cmd button on your page. Type the url into a cell above your webcontrol. In the code of the cmd button,  declare a variable linkname and set it equal to the Range(cell). Then, Call Sheets("Sheet1").WebControl1.Navigate (linkname) and see if that works

Comment: @YiteZeng probably just a limitation of the browser in excel, i wouldn't worry about it. Thanks for the accept. :)